# Magicsuggest : public method getRawValue() returns blank

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magicsuggest

I loaded the magicSuggest control values though a ajax request, it populates well but when i am trying to fetch the user typed text from the div using **getRawValue** its always returns me blank. Though it returns me valid value when i use **getValue**(), but i also need the text.
After debugging found the '**ms.input.val()**' is always set to the default text even after the selection change is triggered.
I also tried using the **getSelectedItems(),** once he object is returned, tried using object property to retrieve the value, eg:**object.fullname**, where fullname is my displayField, but it fails giving unidentified
Have posted the question on Github as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. As Chris said, getRawValue gets the text from the input box in which the user is currently typing. If you want the text from the selection, you need to go through getSelectedItems method and then extract the name property from your objects.

For example if your text property is name:

```
$('#ms1').magicSuggest().getSelectedItems().map(function(a){return a.name;})
```

will return ["selected1", "selected2", ...]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found, getRawValue only works on text before it has become a "selected item". So if you try just typing in a string, without allowing it to select an actual item, then call getRawValue, that should return you some information.

I would have suggested what you stated in the second part, using getSelectedValues() - and then reading your display fields from the objects. I do something similar in the project I'm working on at the moment which works, can you share your code?